Any practical use for the underscore variable?
When we run a command the last argument is saved in _ which we can access:
$ echo $_

Doesn't sound like a terribly useful feature. So why bother? Are there any practical applications?

Note that in bash, $_ has several meanings. See Understand the meaning of `$_`

What counts as practical varies from person to person. I can easily imagine any use being dismissed as "oh, but that can be done with ... "

Interestingly, I thought Rosetta Code would prove instructive under the entry "Topic variable". There you'll find  Perl, Ruby, Raku, and PowerShell all listed as using $_ for the "Topic variable".  However UNIX Shell is listed as using $? as the "Topic variable". See: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Topic_variable#UNIX_Shell

@jubilatious1, umh, the shell's $? has pretty much nothing to do with Perl's $_, or Python's _... $? is closer to errno in C. Those kinds of listings are always something to be taken with a grain of salt.

So you're saying Rosetta Code is wrong regarding its "Topic variable" entry for "Unix Shell"?  Again, this is the link I'm referencing: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Topic_variable#UNIX_Shell

@jubilatious1, I'm saying that the shell's $? has a lot more to do with C's errno, than with something like Perl's $_. The example there relies on awkwardly using the exit status to return the result of a computation. That's not a good idea to do, first, because the value range is really limited, and second, because the idea of the exit status is to tell if the command or function succeeded or failed.

I would also suggest taking listings like that with a grain or two of salt, but I can't say they're "wrong", because they're free to define the concept of a "topic variable" so that it includes that awkward use of $?.

I've noticed that my Basta bash extension breaks interactive $_.  The value of $_ appears correct until the 15 second timer in Basta goes off and refereshes the status bar (so the time updates). The commands executed by the trap handler will clobber $_.  The interrupt must save and restore the value of $_. I will fix it.

It has interactive uses, and can be exploited to perpetrate "code golfing".
It can reduce code by avoiding the need for a temporary variable, like:
temp=$destdir/$outfile
cp $infile $temp
chmod go-w $temp

to
cp $infile $destdir/$outfile
chmod go-w $_

I don't see this $_ feature among the Special Parameters of POSIX; it is a Bash extension (possibly in other shells).
It is a badly implemented hack, which breaks when you set a debug trap, as demonstrated by the following script:
#!/bin/bash

dbg()
{
  :
}

echo abc
echo $_

trap dbg debug

echo abc
echo $_

The output under Bash 4.4.20 is:
$ ./underscore.sh
abc
abc
abc
dbg

You can see that when we enable the debug trap, $_ no longer takes on the expected value abc after echo abc. In the specification of $_, "last command" literally refers to the most recently executed command, not the previous command in the command sequence.
You definitely don't want to be using this in any Bash program that anyone might ever want to debug with a debugger that is implemented with the help of the debug trap.
Interactive use of $_ is the same: refer to the last argument of the previous command. This raises the question: why would anyone use this instead of one of the commands M-_ or M-. which expand the same item into the command line?
The differences in $_ are that:

It is much more compact than the expansion of a long path.

When a command with $_ is recalled from history, it no longer refers to its own predecessor in history, but to whatever command was most recently executed. This can be exploited. We can recall and re-use a command that contains $_ to operate on the most recently used right argument, rather than to exactly repeat an old command with the same arguments.

The content produced by M. is based on the raw, unexpanded command line, whereas $_ produces the actual last argument of the previous command. We can show this difference like so:
$ echo a{b,c}
ab ac
$ echo $_
ac
$ echo a{b,c}
$ echo █

At the point indicated by the cursor block █, type the M. command. Meta M may be Esc or the Alt modifier. The result is:
$ echo a{b,c}█

In other words, the raw non-whitespace last token a{b,c} from the previous command is inserted, rather than the semantic item ac. This looks like more of a GNU Readline feature than a feature of GNU Bash.



I have to say that "code golfing" is the worst way to describe it. Is that really its only purpose? Not as a convenience shortcut or anything, just "code golfing"?

@u1686_grawity, interactively, it's not code golfing, it's keystroke saving. There are better alternatives than $_ for that though like line editor widgets that do the same or csh-style history expansion. For a start, that $_ (like all parameter expansions in bash) should be quoted ("$_").

@u1686_grawity I think if you use this in a program, outside of a code golfing contest, you should be flogged with a wet noodle.  For one thing, I seem to recall that it breaks under debugging. If you have a debug trap that executes commands after every command, it messes with $_.  Also, $_ is not in POSIX; I'm looking at the spect and don't see it among the Special Parameters.

Question is tagged [tag:bash] so it's not really POSIX anyway

@Kaz: You're the one describing its use in programs. Can you elaborate more on the "interactive use" as well?

@u1686_grawity Yes, I updated the answer. While there is a way to literally expand the last word of the previous command into the current command line, using $_ is usefully different from doing that.

$_ is not from bash, it's likely from ksh. Was already there in ksh85. More generally there are very few things that bash invented.

it's not a special parameter in Bash either, since actually, _ is just a regular variable name and you can assign to it, or unset it. Just that it gets re-set immediately after, so that's not too useful. It's listed in Bash Variables. I got this mixed up when editing the title of the Q the first time.

@ilkkachu I got mixed up reading the man page in bash.  It's the first variable listed in a new section immediately after the Special Variables section.

@Kaz, and it looks like in older version of the man page it was listed among the special parameters.

@ilkkachu In fact, that's what I was looking at at first, right! I see it in an Ubuntu 18 VM, which has Bash 4.4.20. Where I see the correction is in a Debian 12 system that has Bash 5.1.4.

@Kaz, thanks for all that. It sounds more interesting than I thought. I didn't get the M-x_ you mentioned. Is that a command?

@user9101329 This is an error. The command is actually M-_ (meta-underscore, or concretely ESC-underscore). Also M-. does it.

I use it often in the combo
mkdir verylongdirectoryname
cd $_


You could use Alt + . to insert last parameter (on emacs mode)

!$ also works. It also expands to the last parameter.
